# Loading from CSV data from S3 into AWS RDS Mysql

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

So as the question suggests, I am looking for a command similar to the "copy" command of redhsifts which allows me to load csv data stored in an S3 buckets directly into a AWS RDS Mysql table ( it's not aurora).
How do I do that?

Comment: See [Load S3 Data into Amazon RDS MySQL Table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-template-copys3tords.html).

Comment: I would like a command of logic based approach if possible instead of data pipeline

Answer (score -2):

Just migrate your database to aurora, then use `LOAD DATA INFILE FROM S3 's3://<your-file-location>/<filename>.csv'`

Careful though if you are using big CSV files - you'll have to manage timeouts and tune your instance to have a fast write capacity.